# In Shor's algorithm, how can we guarantee that each controlled-U will kickback to the same eigenvalue?

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation, phase-kickback

I'm studying the Shor algorithm as part of my thesis and have a question about the "measured" phases after the QPE.

So, I take the controlled-U operations on the second register and in cause of phase kickback the relative phase of the controll qubit in register one will change with a multiple of the eigenvalue of $U$. I understand, that $cU$ has multiple eigenvalues with a factor $s$. How can be guaranteed that each of the controlled-Us will kickback the same eigenvalue? Or, why it is not important?

Second, if I run the controlled-U operations and make the QPE, why it is possible to get different results? I thought that the transformation between the bases is unique. So, if my controlled-U makes a specific "change" on the quibit, how it is possible that the QPE generates a superposition with specific probabilities? (e.g. in Nielsen/Chuang Box 5.4 the final measurement will give 0, 512, 1024, 1536)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand, that cU has multiple eigenvalues with a factor s. How
> can be guaranteed that each of the controlled-Us will kickback the
> same eigenvalue? Or, why it is not important?

All the $U$s in the various controlled-$U$ are the *same* $U$, with the same eigenvectors and the same eigenvalues. This is part of the construction of the circuit, and provides the guarantee that you are seeking.

> Second, if I run the controlled-U operations and make the QPE, why it
> is possible to get different results?

Remember that, for QPE, if you input an eigenvector of $U$ (and if that eigenvalue has an exact $t$-bit representation) then a $t$-bit QPE will give exactly the eigenvalue, no probabilities.

However, for Shor's algorithm, we cannot create an eigenvector - it requires knowledge of the value $s/r$, which is exactly what we're trying to find out! So, instead of inputting an eigenvector, we input $|1\rangle$, which is a superposition of several different eigenvectors. By linearity, the end result is a superposition of several different possible eigenvalues, and when we measure, the measurement just finds one of those values at random.

Comment: thank you, that was the part I not understand. But, refer to this [link](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html#2.1-Counting-in-the-Fourier-basis:-) we see the transformation between computational basis and  Fourier basis. Are the qubits before QPE already in superposition in Fourier basis? Or why we get different values after the QPE?

Comment: If you supplied an eigenvector, the qubits before the fourier transform would be in the fourier basis. So, when we don't supply an eigenvector, they're in a superposition of states in the fourier basis.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this document? https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/shor.html

Note that in Shor's algorithm, we use the quantum computer as a subroutine to essentially find the period of the function

$$ f(x) = a^x mod N$$

where $a$ is a  guessed value between $1$ and $N-1$. So you have to create **different** circuit to implement each of the guessed $a$.

---

As for the QPE step, this is essentially as follow:

Let's suppose that

$$ U|\psi\rangle = e^{2\pi i \phi} |\psi\rangle$$

then

$$U^{2^j}|\psi \rangle = U^{2^j -1}\bigg(U|\psi\rangle\bigg) = U^{2^j -1}\bigg( e^{2\pi i \phi} |\psi\rangle\bigg) = \cdots =  e^{2\pi i 2^j \phi} |\psi \rangle$$

The phase-kickback turn each of the ancilla qubit (after going through Hadamard gate) from the state $\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ to the state $\dfrac{ |0\rangle + e^{2\pi i 2^j \phi}|1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ under $CU^{2^j}$ operator. To be mathematical precise,

$$CU^{2^j}:  \bigg( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( |0\rangle + |1\rangle \big) \bigg)|\psi\rangle  \to \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg( |0\rangle |\psi \rangle + |1\rangle e^{2\pi i 2^j \phi} |\psi\rangle \bigg) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg( |0\rangle + e^{2\pi i 2^j \phi}  |1\rangle \bigg)|\psi\rangle $$

Now if you apply the inverse QFT to all the ancilla qubit then you will get the binary expression of $\phi$.

---

Comment: Yes, I have studied the documents. My problem which I not understand is: How are the qubits "designed" after $H$ and $U^{2^j}$ and measurement of the second register? If i plot the Bloch, there still in $|+\rangle$. Is this because of the superposition over all possible $\theta$ and they sum up to $|+\rangle$ before QFT?